# NSDate region format issue

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];
NSDate *selectedDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        selectedDate = [dtFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",    [appDelegate.aryTime objectAtIndex:i]]];        
    NSLog(@"selected Date: %@", selectedDate);
    NSLog(@"Today Date: %@", todayDate);

    int interval = [todayDate compare:selectedDate];
```

I've this code. Now, what happens is while I run the app keeping the region format (From Settings>General>International>set region format) of UK (where they use AM and PM) the app compares both the dates fine. But if I change my region format to Sweden (where they use em and fm instead), the dates are not being compared.Is there any way where I can remove the dependency of region format and compare dates? I tried converting them in 24 hr formats but that didn't help.

Comment: I think Sweden uses a 24h-clock, not "em/fm".

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two date with following way ..

==> extend in built NSDate Class (.h as well as .m files)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
struct DateInformation {
int day;
int month;
int year;
int weekday;
int minute;
int hour;
int second;
 };
  typedef struct DateInformation DateInformation;
  @interface NSDate (Extra)
   - (DateInformation) dateInformation;
   @end
```

implementation class:

```
#import "NSDate+Extra.h"

  @implementation NSDate (Extra)

- (DateInformation) dateInformation
   {
DateInformation info;
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) 
                                      fromDate:self];
info.day = [comp day];
info.month = [comp month];
info.year = [comp year];

info.hour = [comp hour];
info.minute = [comp minute];
info.second = [comp second];

info.weekday = [comp weekday];


[gregorian release];
return info;
    }

@end
```

from the class where you want to compare to dates

do following for both dates

```
 NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
 DateInformation info=[date dateInformation];
   NSLog(@"%@",info);

 NSDate *date1=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1242141];
 DateInformation info=[date1 dateInformation];
   NSLog(@"%@",info);
```

implement  one more method in extended date class for comparing all the parameter of date which are integer..

hope it can help you

regards,
neil